# Android:where to save audio files for allowing user to dowload it if he wants

Tags: android, button, audio, download, store

I am Developing an app for playing audio files  (rhymes) .
But to limit the size of the app i want to add a functionality of download button for the specific audio files.
Idea is- I would provide them 10-15 pre-embedded audio and other audios can be downloaded if they want.
But i don't know how to do it.
Where to upload it.
Or can it be Stored in some external database.which can be accessed by the user.
I don't want to make the app size very large.
Thanks

Comment: you can host your audio files over dropbox and can provide a method to download them to the sdcard of device if user wants to use them

Comment: Yes,This is what i want..

Comment: then check for "how to use dropbox api and how to download and save file to sdcard "

Comment: Can you please give me an example through the code..assuming audio has been uploaded to the dropbox..

Comment: i have never used dropbox api , u can search for it on google or here itself , i am pretty sure u'll get some